How to mount sftp server with sshfs
It is simple enough to connect sftp server with lftp command without any key or password :
lftp  192.168.31.130:3721
lftp 192.168.31.130:~> ls
drwxr-xr-x 1 nobody nobody         3488 Dec 22 20:17 Android
drwxr-xr-x 1 nobody nobody         3488 Jul 29 00:43 MIUI

Now I want to mount the sftp server with sshfs:
sudo sshfs  192.168.31.130:3721  /tmp/localdir
read: Connection reset by peer
sudo sshfs  192.168.31.130:3721  /tmp/localdir  -o allow_other
read: Connection reset by peer

How can I mount sftp server with sshfs ?
More info on 192.168.31.130:3721.
I installed ES File Explorer on my android phone,and activate function "view on pc",3721 is port ,the protocol is FTP,start the FTP server using ES File Explorer on my android phone.


(1) lftp supports many protocols. Are you sure 192.168.31.130:3721 uses SSH? If it uses something else, sshfs won't work. (2) I expect sshfs to interpret 3721 in 192.168.31.130:3721 as path, not as port. What if you do sshfs -p 3721 192.168.31.130:  /tmp/localdir? (3) sudo will run sshfs locally as root, so unless the local config (/homedir_of_root/.ssh/config, /etc/ssh/ssh_config) specifies a different remote user, the remote user will also be root. Does the server allow ssh-ing in as root? Doing this with allow_other will be extremely insecure.

The FUSE for FTP was curlftpfs. I don't know its status in 2024.

SFTP and FTP are totally unrelated protocols. You cannot run an sshfs client on top of an FTP service.
In the documentation, man sshfs, the section DESCRIPTION writes

SSHFS allows you to mount a remote filesystem using SSH (more precisely, the SFTP subsystem).

It goes on to say,

It is recommended to run SSHFS as regular user (not as root). For this to work the mountpoint must be owned by the user.  If username is omitted SSHFS will use the local username. If the directory is omitted, SSHFS will mount the (remote) home directory.

